# How to not override my key every time I send data to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to save strings to local storage submitted from a textbox and submit button. However the data overwrites every time a new string is submitted as the key stays the same. How do I use a new key every time so data is saved. I view the key value pairs via inspect.

I have tired using the following but .length is just reding the length of the string and is not correct. I have also tried localStorage.length. Is there a simple solution to this, it doesnt have to be a for loop. I have researched but not understood anything.

> function setLocalStorage() {

```
let data = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    localStorage.setItem("Key" + (i + 1), data)
};

document.getElementById("textBox").value = "";

}
```

Comment: You are just overwriting data in localStorage. By doing so, you need to have array first ex: ```let arr =[];``` Then ```array.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(array));``` in this case  you are like inserting new data in the localStorage.

Comment: You should think of local storage as a key-value store. Every time you call `localStorage.setItem(key, value)`, the value for the particular key gets created or replaced. For example, if you need to store userId and useAddress, you need to call `localStorage.setItem('userId', '1')` and `localStorage.setItem('userAddress', 'Test Address')` separately. And if you need to change the address, u can call `localStorage.setItem('userAddress', 'Test Address New')` again to change the value for the local storage item for `userAddress`.